# Гарбузине насіння?

Tags: прикметники, словотворення

Учора дивилася в театрі ім. Франка чудову виставу "Грек Зорба".

Головний герой у виконанні Анатолія Хостікоєва в одному із монологів ужив дивний прикметник у вислові "**гарбуз*ин*е насіння**".

СУМ у значенні прикметника до **`ГАРБУЗ`** подає [**ГАРБУЗО́ВИЙ**, а, е.](http://sum.in.ua/s/gharbuzovyj), а як діалектичне [**ГАРБУЗЯ́ЧИЙ**, а, е, діал.](http://sum.in.ua/s/gharbuzjachyj)

Те ж саме бачимо у [Словнику української мови Бориса Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/8806-gharbuzovyj.html#show_point)

Знаю, що як іменник [ГАРБУЗИНА](http://pidruchniki.com/1840062049153/ekologiya/klasifikatsiya_plodiv) вживається для позначення плоду рослин родини гарбузових (гарбуз, огірок, диня, кавун). І хоч СУМ не містить такого слова, я його зустрічала раніше.

А от як прикметник **`гарбузиний`** не чула до вчора. Пошукала в мережі. Знайшла "**`гарбузиний печворк городу`**" в есе Маргарити Проніної ["Запах осені"](http://probapera.org/publication/13/38375/zapah-oseni.html).

Може, хто зустрічав **`гарбузиний`** у якомусь із словників (принаймні, діалектизмів) чи це просто авторське словотворення (за співзвучністю із `журавлиний`, `горобиний`)?

Answer (score 2):

Окрім гарбуза (і його насіння) є також слово гарбузина́. У СУМі я такого слова не знайшов, але це слово є у вікіпедії, а також на сайті beaplanet.ru у розділі "види плодів".

Цитата з [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#.D0.91.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81):

> Плід — багатонасінна гарбузина́<sup>4</sup>, іноді величезного розміру, або зовсім м'яка, або з більш-менш твердим, дерев'янистим зовнішнім шаром (напр. у Lagenaria, Cucurbita та ін.)
>   <sub><sup>4</sup> Раніше її не відрізняли від ягоди, але в сучасній ботанічній літературі гарбузина вважається самостійним підтипом плоду, див., напр. Артюшенко З. А., Федоров Ал. А.Атлас з описової морфології вищих рослин. Плід. — Л.: Наука, 1986. — С.10.</sub>

На сайті з видами плодів [стаття](http://beaplanet.ru/kvytkovy_roslini/vidi_plodyv/garbuzina.html) починається так:

> Гарбузина відноситься до численної групи плодів-ценокарпіїв. Плід багатонасінний, що формується з нижньої зав'язі. За будовою він нагадує ягоду, але відрізняється від неї структурою оплодня та великою кількістю насінин. Прикладами гарбузини є гарбуз, огірок, диня, кавун.

Можливо від "гарбузини" можна утворити "гарбузине" насіння?

Comment: А ще є слово [гарбузи́ння](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17716&page=595).

Comment: А, упс, туплю, про огірок, диню, кавун є прямо у Вашій відповіді.

Comment: @Sasha, зауважте, не тільки у відповіді, а й у запитанні)

Comment: @Artemix, дякую за відповідь. Інтуїтивно і я припускаю,що могло би так утворитися. Але не чула ніколи раніше. Хоч у дитинстві у бабусі в селі стільки того *гарбузового* (не *гарбузиного*) насіння перелускано)

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko Я думаю що навряд чи це "гарбузине" насіння (а особливо у "Зорбі") було утворено саме з гарбузини, просто що таке слово можливе. У книзі "Кумедні й лихі пригоди Алексіса Зорбаса" (переклад українською Анатолія Чердаклі 1989 року) все-таки "гарбузове" насіння. А виставу поставлено за книгою "Я, грек Зорба" у перекладі Анатолія Бондаренка (але я знайшов таку книгу лише російською), отже може це такий "екзотичний" переклад.

Comment: @Artemix, щодо "Зорби", то у мене два варіанти: 1) оскільки це переклад з грецької, то може бути авторське (але треба читати сценарій); 2) спершу подумала, що діалектизм і Хостікоєв просто вжив його несвідомо (виринуло з пам'яті десь), але ж не знаходжу у словниках. Власне, так і сформулювалось запитання.